# Is there anyway to automatically add Facebook posts to your wordpress posts?

Tags: wordpress, facebook, plugins, rss

There seems to be a lot of plugins and how-tos on automatically posting wordpress posts to facebook page. How can I reverse this?

For example, I post a update on Facebook page and it automatically adds that update in the form of a post to my wordpress website.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can probably do that with a [ifttt](https://ifttt.com) recipe, for example this might work:

- [When I post a status to facebook, publish it on wordpress](https://ifttt.com/recipes/17171-when-i-post-a-status-to-facebook-publish-it-on-wordpress)
- [Rss Feed To WordPress post](https://ifttt.com/recipes/127385-rss-feed-to-wordpress-post)

Comment: wow this seems very interesting - just might be what I'm looking for. thanks!